# Typo 3 v9 - routeEnhancers

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

So, for first: I'm currently sitting on the wrong site of the project, having to deal with typo 3 the first time (I'm usually building APIs). So please answer in detail, what I need to try ;)

And here we go:
I need to create a plugin which shows different contents loaded by an API and it should go by pretty urls (like /provider/{id}/{name}/jobs) and so on.

The plugin itself seems to be registered correctly (at least when I load it into a page it does what I expected)

But now I try to get it going with pretty urls so I tried these routeEnhancers - and they totally ignore me and always fail into a 404.

Here my config.yaml

```
rootPageId: 1
...
routes:
  -
    route: ''
    type: uri
routeEnhancers:
  ProviderCompass:
    type: Plugin
    limitToPages: [28]
    routePath: '/provider/{provider}'
    namespace: 'tx_providercompass_aboutus'
    requirements:
      provider: '[0-9]'
```

I tried it with different namespaces (without the tx_ or using the "real" "wfm" namespace) and also with the Extbase type - but it didn't work either.

Always a 404 when trying to access /provider/123
So what am I missing?

And yes, I cleared the caches...

Comment: So just to cross-check: the 28 is actually the page where this provider detail plugin is? (you can remove that constraint for testing to rule that out)

Comment: Yes, there the plugin is loaded. But currently without an argument „provider“ in the action.

Comment: Without argument "provider" it would not make a lot of sense. So that is not the detail action I guess, rather the list?

If this is an extbase plugin (see which class your controller extends), you might want to use type: Extbase

Then try to let TYPO3 build an URL to the detail page. For example put this in any Fluid template that gets rendered on your page: 
<f:uri.action pageUid="28" extensionName="providercompass" pluginName="yourPluginName" controller="yourController" action="yourAction" arguments="{provider: 123}"/>

Comment: I know it wouldn’t make much sense, but at least it shouldn’t fail with a 404. But I’ll try to generate this url - although: does this really matter? I mean I configured the url in the config.yaml

Comment: The Controller extends the ActionController, puttingthe provider arg in the action makes no difference

Comment: How do the generated URLs look like? Are they exactly what you expect?

Comment: Well well... it came out I did nothing wrong, but cHash prevented me to test the urls directly and all the <f:link (or what it was called - currently at home not in the company to see the code) created wrong links / didn’t create pretty urls. So I created a new viewhelper to generate them (which was also a pain to get the UriBuilder working in a ViewHelper) to generate the urls. And I also deactivated the cHash GET thingy in the settings.

Comment: The 404 on unresolvable routes is by design. I gave a hint how you could see what your config does. What you configured did not allow 123 actually due to missing star [0-9]*. It is absolutely possible to get the urls you want and without cHash of course.